# Creating a custom page for admin to add products

Tags: php, magento, module

Can we make a simple form in magento for admin to add products and other required details rather than using the default menu which is for the admin after login ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below function in controller to add new product

```
public function addNewProduct(Varien_Object $object){

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

        $product->setSku('pro12'); 
        $product->setAttributeSetId(9);
        $product->setTypeId('simple');
        $product->setName('Product title');
        $product->setCategoryIds(array(7));
        $product->setWebsiteIDs(array(1));
        $product->setDescription('Product Full description');
        $product->setShortDescription('Product Short description');
        $product->setPrice(250.00);
        $product->setWeight(30.00);
        $product->setVisibility(4);
        $product->setStatus(1);
        $product->setTaxClassId(0);
        $product->setStockData(array(
           'is_in_stock' => 1,
            'qty' => 20
        ));
        $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));

        try { 
            $product->save(); 
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) { 
            Mage::log($e->getMessage()); //check your var/log/system.log for error
        } 

        echo "saved";
        die();  
    }
```

Also to design form use [this link](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-admin-form-field) to take necessary input from admin and you can add your product with simple form.

Comment: @user2147366, welcome, i would be glad if you accept my answer, so someone can use for future reference if the have requirement to add product from other view of form.

Comment: @user2147366, thanks, glad to help you. please vote up my answer so some one can trust in our thread.